# Alias for JDK is not working in ZSH but works in bash

Tags: zsh

The following aliases are working in bash but not in ZSH:

```
# Different installed version of JDK
export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
export JAVA_11_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)

alias java8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME'
alias java11='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_11_HOME'

# default to Java 11
java11
```

I only get the following error:

```
zsh: command not found: java8
```

I can change the JDK version if I do it like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

But the alias java8 or java11 are not recognised.

Comment: They need to be added to a `zsh` configuration file if you want to use them in `zsh`.

Comment: They are inside .zshrc and .bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming these all appear in your `.bashrc` file. You need to add them to `.zshrc` for `zsh` to define them.